# which makes sense for this case - class vs interface vs abstract?

Tags: c#, oop

I have a "Package" table in database.

A Package can be of three types: Package A, Package B and Package C.

All the three package have some common fields like
1)name
2)size
3)weight

Now coming to the unique fields:

Package A & B must contain -
a)channel

Package C must contain -
a)completion

So, I create a table called as "Package" in database.
Columns of "Package" then would be:

1)id
2)type (1 = PackageA, 2 = PackageB, 3 = PackageC)
3)name
4)size
5)weight
6)channel (not required for Package C)
6)completion (not required for Package A & B)

So, I create an abstract class like below (ignoring datatypes of the properties):

```
public abstract class Package
{
public id;  
public type;
public name;  
public size;    
public weight;  
}

public class PackageA : Package
{
public channel;
}


public class PackageB : Package
{
public channel;
}

public class PackageC : Package
{
public completion;
}
```

what would I be doing wrong with this approach? Should the Package class be abstract or simply class?
Since I would not want other to work directly on Package class and instead take on Package A,B,C.

EDIT: What about the database part? Is it common to have fields/column like "channel"(needed for Package A & B) (not needed for Package C) and "completion"(needed for Package C)(not needed for Package A & B) to have "null" when not needed/used for specific package type?

Comment: Your approach is just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that's wrong with this approach is that `channel` is duplicated across `PackageA` and `PackageB`. You could fix it by adding another base class for the two package types that share a `channel`:

```
public abstract class PackageWithChannel : Package {
    public Channel Channel {get;set;}
}
public class PackageA : PackageWithChannel {
   ...
}
public class PackageB : PackageWithChannel {
   ...
}
```

This eliminates duplication of the `Channel` property.

As for the database part, there are different ways of mapping a class hierarchy to an RDBMS, ranging from a single table for attribute-value lists to a table-per-hierarchy with a type field. You picked a table-per-hierarchy, which is entirely valid.

Comment: BTW in my case usually I don't design a new class for the sake of a single shared property.

Comment: I have added an EDIT to my original question.